# nginx fails installation in Debian stable

Tags: debian, nginx

When I try to install `nginx` with `apt`, this is the error I get:

```
Selecting previously unselected package nginx-common.
(Reading database ... 137404 files and directories currently installed.)
Preparing to unpack .../00-nginx-common_1.10.3-1+deb9u1_all.deb ...
Unpacking nginx-common (1.10.3-1+deb9u1) ...
Selecting previously unselected package libnginx-mod-http-auth-pam.
Preparing to unpack .../01-libnginx-mod-http-auth-pam_1.10.3-1+deb9u1_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking libnginx-mod-http-auth-pam (1.10.3-1+deb9u1) ...
Selecting previously unselected package libnginx-mod-http-dav-ext.
Preparing to unpack .../02-libnginx-mod-http-dav-ext_1.10.3-1+deb9u1_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking libnginx-mod-http-dav-ext (1.10.3-1+deb9u1) ...
Selecting previously unselected package libnginx-mod-http-echo.
Preparing to unpack .../03-libnginx-mod-http-echo_1.10.3-1+deb9u1_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking libnginx-mod-http-echo (1.10.3-1+deb9u1) ...
Selecting previously unselected package libnginx-mod-http-geoip.
Preparing to unpack .../04-libnginx-mod-http-geoip_1.10.3-1+deb9u1_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking libnginx-mod-http-geoip (1.10.3-1+deb9u1) ...
Selecting previously unselected package libnginx-mod-http-image-filter.
Preparing to unpack .../05-libnginx-mod-http-image-filter_1.10.3-1+deb9u1_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking libnginx-mod-http-image-filter (1.10.3-1+deb9u1) ...
Selecting previously unselected package libnginx-mod-http-subs-filter.
Preparing to unpack .../06-libnginx-mod-http-subs-filter_1.10.3-1+deb9u1_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking libnginx-mod-http-subs-filter (1.10.3-1+deb9u1) ...
Selecting previously unselected package libnginx-mod-http-upstream-fair.
Preparing to unpack .../07-libnginx-mod-http-upstream-fair_1.10.3-1+deb9u1_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking libnginx-mod-http-upstream-fair (1.10.3-1+deb9u1) ...
Selecting previously unselected package libnginx-mod-http-xslt-filter.
Preparing to unpack .../08-libnginx-mod-http-xslt-filter_1.10.3-1+deb9u1_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking libnginx-mod-http-xslt-filter (1.10.3-1+deb9u1) ...
Selecting previously unselected package libnginx-mod-mail.
Preparing to unpack .../09-libnginx-mod-mail_1.10.3-1+deb9u1_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking libnginx-mod-mail (1.10.3-1+deb9u1) ...
Selecting previously unselected package libnginx-mod-stream.
Preparing to unpack .../10-libnginx-mod-stream_1.10.3-1+deb9u1_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking libnginx-mod-stream (1.10.3-1+deb9u1) ...
Selecting previously unselected package nginx-full.
Preparing to unpack .../11-nginx-full_1.10.3-1+deb9u1_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking nginx-full (1.10.3-1+deb9u1) ...
Selecting previously unselected package nginx.
Preparing to unpack .../12-nginx_1.10.3-1+deb9u1_all.deb ...
Unpacking nginx (1.10.3-1+deb9u1) ...
Processing triggers for ufw (0.35-4) ...
Setting up nginx-common (1.10.3-1+deb9u1) ...
Created symlink /etc/systemd/system/multi-user.target.wants/nginx.service → /lib/systemd/system/nginx.service.
Setting up libnginx-mod-http-image-filter (1.10.3-1+deb9u1) ...
Setting up libnginx-mod-http-subs-filter (1.10.3-1+deb9u1) ...
Processing triggers for systemd (232-25+deb9u1) ...
Setting up libnginx-mod-http-auth-pam (1.10.3-1+deb9u1) ...
Setting up libnginx-mod-http-dav-ext (1.10.3-1+deb9u1) ...
Setting up libnginx-mod-mail (1.10.3-1+deb9u1) ...
Processing triggers for man-db (2.7.6.1-2) ...
Setting up libnginx-mod-http-xslt-filter (1.10.3-1+deb9u1) ...
Setting up libnginx-mod-http-upstream-fair (1.10.3-1+deb9u1) ...
Setting up libnginx-mod-http-geoip (1.10.3-1+deb9u1) ...
Setting up libnginx-mod-stream (1.10.3-1+deb9u1) ...
Setting up libnginx-mod-http-echo (1.10.3-1+deb9u1) ...
Setting up nginx-full (1.10.3-1+deb9u1) ...
Job for nginx.service failed because the control process exited with error code.
See "systemctl status nginx.service" and "journalctl -xe" for details.
invoke-rc.d: initscript nginx, action "start" failed.
● nginx.service - A high performance web server and a reverse proxy server
   Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/nginx.service; enabled; vendor preset: enabled)
   Active: failed (Result: exit-code) since Wed 2018-01-03 08:12:19 GMT; 35ms ago
     Docs: man:nginx(8)
  Process: 1563 ExecStart=/usr/sbin/nginx -g daemon on; master_process on; (code=exited, status=1/FAILURE)
  Process: 1561 ExecStartPre=/usr/sbin/nginx -t -q -g daemon on; master_process on; (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)

Jan 03 08:12:17 testingBed nginx[1563]: nginx: [emerg] listen() to [::]:80, …se)
Jan 03 08:12:18 testingBed nginx[1563]: nginx: [emerg] listen() to 0.0.0.0:8…se)
Jan 03 08:12:18 testingBed nginx[1563]: nginx: [emerg] listen() to [::]:80, …se)
Jan 03 08:12:18 testingBed nginx[1563]: nginx: [emerg] listen() to 0.0.0.0:8…se)
Jan 03 08:12:18 testingBed nginx[1563]: nginx: [emerg] listen() to [::]:80, …se)
Jan 03 08:12:19 testingBed nginx[1563]: nginx: [emerg] still could not bind()
Jan 03 08:12:19 testingBed systemd[1]: nginx.service: Control process exite…us=1
Jan 03 08:12:19 testingBed systemd[1]: Failed to start A high performance w…ver.
Jan 03 08:12:19 testingBed systemd[1]: nginx.service: Unit entered failed state.
Jan 03 08:12:19 testingBed systemd[1]: nginx.service: Failed with result 'e…de'.
Hint: Some lines were ellipsized, use -l to show in full.
dpkg: error processing package nginx-full (--configure):
 subprocess installed post-installation script returned error exit status 1
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of nginx:
 nginx depends on nginx-full (<< 1.10.3-1+deb9u1.1~) | nginx-light (<< 1.10.3-1+deb9u1.1~) | nginx-extras (<< 1.10.3-1+deb9u1.1~); however:
  Package nginx-full is not configured yet.
  Package nginx-light is not installed.
  Package nginx-extras is not installed.
 nginx depends on nginx-full (>= 1.10.3-1+deb9u1) | nginx-light (>= 1.10.3-1+deb9u1) | nginx-extras (>= 1.10.3-1+deb9u1); however:
  Package nginx-full is not configured yet.
  Package nginx-light is not installed.
  Package nginx-extras is not installed.

dpkg: error processing package nginx (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
Processing triggers for ufw (0.35-4) ...
Errors were encountered while processing:
 nginx-full
 nginx
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

Comment: error msg says nginx can't bind (to port 80).  Do you have another web server or anything else already listening on port 80?  perhaps apache, or an older version of nginix?

Comment: @cas Yup. Apache was running. Stopped it and now it works fine. Could you answer the question so that I can accept your answer and close the question out?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The error msg says that `nginx` can't bind (to port 80).

The most likely cause is that you have another web server already listening on port 80 - perhaps `apache`, or an older version of `nginx`.

If that's the case, stop the old web server and continue the installation with:

```
dpkg --configure --pending
```

Another alternative would be to configure `nginx` (or apache) to listen on a different port.  8080 is a common and popular choice for "secondary" web servers.  Or on a different IP address if the host machine has multiple IP addresses available to it.